# MergeSort Implementation Stability

Tags: arrays, algorithm, linked-list, quicksort, mergesort

Does the implementation of mergesort affect its stability?

For example, if we use arrays to implement merge sort, is that less stable than a linked list implementation of merge sort?

Comment: A sorting algorithm is stable or it's not. There's no such thing as "less stable."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most implementations of both top down (recursive) and bottom up (iterative) implementations of merge sort for arrays or linked lists will be stable. The key factor is in the merge function, as long as the merge function moves equal "left" elements before "right" elements, it will be stable. The compare can be "left" element <= "right" element or in the case of C++ standard library, which only uses less than for compare, its compare is "right" element < "left" element, so the "left" element will get moved if it is <= "right" element.

Another possible issue would be with a hybrid merge sort that used a non-stable sort method for small groups of elements.

In general, sorts that swap adjacent elements (like bubble sort) are usually stable, while sorts that swap non-adjacent elements (like quick sort) are usually not stable.

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort should be stable with both of them. Wether you use a list or an array depends more on what you're using it for.

Answer (score 0):

A sorting method is stable if it preserve the relative order of elements with equal keys in an array.

Both Top Down and Bottom up implementation are stable approaches. Its independent of array or Linked List.